# Only display $_GET result in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Now my title can be a bit confusing because I don't really know how do describe the problem or question rather in a few words.

So for example, right now I have the members page URL look like this: www.example.com/member.php?username=MyUsername and I have seen webpages with something like this: www.example.com/MyUsername is it possible to like remove the "member.php?username=" bit with .htaccess or PHP? Or do you do it in another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called *pretty URLs*, uses *URL rewriting* and has been discussed a thousand times. These should be the right keywords to get you started.

Comment: Do some research before posting question. If samples doesn't work post question with what you are tried

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?username=$1 [L]
```